# Coroutine start running from send() rather than next()

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine

I am learning coroutine from awesome presentation by David Beazley.[Coroutine](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf)

I am very confused about a simple task example in which a generator start running without a proceeding `next()`

```
class Task(object):
    taskid = 0
    def __init__(self, target):
        Task.taskid += 1
        self.tid    = Task.taskid #Task id
        self.target = target      #Target coroutine
        self.sendval = None  #value to send

    def run(self):
        return self.target.send(self.sendval)

# a very simple generator

def foo():
    print('Part 1')
    yield
    print("Part 2")
    yield
```

It starts without next()

```
In [8]: t1 = Task(foo())                                                                                          
In [9]: t1.run()                                                                                                  
Part 1
```

As to foo

```
In [10]: f1 = foo()                                                                                               

In [11]: f1.send(1)                                                                                               
TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator
```

It should be started with `next()` in advance.

How could I understand this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error description tells you what is wrong and what you should do - you should send `None` to just-created generator. That is `f1.send(None)` instead of `f1.send(1)`. Ususally coroutines are used with the decorator like the one you provided in the question (class `Task` and its method `run`) or like the following one:

```
def coroutine(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        generator = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(generator)
        return generator
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Why task run without invoking next()

Comment: it does not have a decorator.

Comment: `generator.send(None)` is alternative to `next(generator)`. `t1 = Task(foo())` is essentially decorating.

Comment: ty, I got it. foo() is a called function, seem a strange decorating.